# End of Winter/Spring Camping

Tags: camping, cold-weather, winter, spring

Planning a camping trip for next weekend.  It is looking like it may be the end of winter.  We have about a foot of snow right now.  What problems am I going to run into if the weather is above zero and/or we get some rain?

Anyone have any tips on staying comfortable, happy and dry?

So far on my list:

- Packing lots of stove fuel so that if making a fire is impossible we can still heat lots of liquid to drink and stay warm
- Packing two pairs of boots
- Bringing two tarps so that we can add a tarp under our tent to protect from water.  If it rains we will pitch a tarp over our tent and maybe a temporary tarp over us

Other info:

- Going camping in the forest.
- 3km hike in
- Temperature moving around the freezing point
- Overnight this time but interested in longer trips
- About a foot of old snow
- Two people

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a 2 day adventure I wouldn't bring any extra pairs of boots. Just the one wearing. A set of clothes (wearing) and a spare one. Have multiple layers. Hiking in the snow would warm you up good and you don't want to be sweating. I'd bring a poncho as well. Good if it rains and to lay on the ground. If you have show shoes they'd be good as well. Use your sleeping bag to keep your clothes warm over night or dry them if needed. Same with your boots. [Winter Camping: How to warm up your boots in the morning?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/3824/580)

I'm not sure how the weather can fluctuate there, but here in the Rockies, at about and over 3000m we can have a hot sunny day and a cold stormy night. So, based on what you know about the area, be prepared.

Are you bringing a tent? I never do. If not, your tarp idea is great. Set one on the ground as you said and one on an angle, with the opening towards the fire, if you get one started.

I also recommend to get a fire going. It will warm you up and boost the morale any time. In the forest you can always find wood for a fire.

I always carry my wool blanket with me. It's awesome in the winter. Also, if you have a space blanket, just in case. It is small, fits even in a pocket. I don't know where you live, but you can find one at Walmart for like $2.

As for the stove fuel, I'd say one canister is more than enough for 2 days.

Based on the gear you have and the way you handle the weather you can always make improvements and adjustments. I always like to pack light and effective based on the geographical area.

Answer (score 2):

For two days.  I would try to keep water out of your tent. If your clothes are wet wear them outside the tent to try to get them dry. Before getting in the tent take off wet clothes and put them in a plastic bag so the water doesn't evaporate inside.  Knock the snow off boots before bringing them inside. A small sponge to mop up condensation and get it out of the tent can also help.

Dry with a bag rated for the temperature is usually good for a cozy night.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @slybloty and @Mark Gibbons, but add:

**Extra socks are a MUST!  Two extra pair of wool socks are not excessive for the slushy and possibly rainy conditions you describe.**   Remember that a pair of dry socks can substitute for mittens when your mittens get wet.

As for the extra pair of boots, we have never even contemplated taking extra boots, but our hiking and backpacking is mostly in the Sierra and the Rockies.  Your conditions may be more extreme.  Remember that wool is warm even when damp.